# Reloading database entries within same page php

Tags: php, mysql, web, reload

I have created a little website where I display some entries from a database. In the past, there was always a button `update` which I pressed where then an extern PHP script was called to update all the entries based on the changes.

But after some time, this method was getting annoying because I always have to manual go back and refresh the page.

So my question is now how would I prevent that ?

My idea was creating a form with action='' and calling it from an `input type='submit'`. But that leads me to the problem that I don't send the password and username again to the site.

My structure looks like this

```
... html code
<form action='' method='post'>
    <input type='submit' value='update'/>
</form>
<?php
function loadTable()
{
    // auth user ($POST['user'] == username, $POST['pass'] == password)
    // sql query
    // building html table
}
loadTable()
?>
```

Regards

Comment: Do you mean you want to make it something like when you load the page so it should have directly each and everything or what??

Comment: You can pretty much do that by removing the function and also the update form..it's simple..!

Comment: my load table function gets each entry out of the database. But the problem occurs when I want to update an entry because I am using as you can see I am asking for the username and password in the loadTable function thus the page refresh always shows me invalid username and password.

Comment: so then keep the username and password in an array in a session or you can save the username and password in a cookie whatever you like..!

Comment: Thanks ! I will try that

Comment: You are comparing your username  and password to what in your `function loadTable()` ? as I can see these are  constants ..! ??

Comment: I am including a PHP file where are my password and username are stored. So yea these are constants.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well..Here is a way exactly how you can do this :

**Note :** Upon loading the page you can save your username and password in a Session like this way as :

```
<?php
session_start();
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
$username = $POST['user'];
$password = $POST['pass'];
$_SESSION['user_credentials'] = array( "username" => $username , "password" => $password );

} else {
// Redirect back to index.php if user credentials are not posted from the form
header("Location: index.php");
?>
```

Then Later you can add something like this in your `function loadTable()` as :

```
<?php
session_start();
function loadTable()
{
    $user_session = $_SESSION['user_credentials'];
    // Now you can access your username and password like this way as :
    if ($user_session['username'] == username && $user_session['password'] == password) 
    { /*do whatever you want*/ }
    // sql query
    // building html table
}
?>
```

**Note :** Place `session_start();` just right after your PHP starting tag as `<?php` in every file where you are intending to create a session or accessing an already created session.

Comment: So if I have it understand correctly I will have to create a session at my login.php (where the user will log his self in) then I redirect him to the showtable.php, where the loadTable function gets called. Where I then can use the session.

Comment: @Sens4 : Yes..Exactly once a Session is created it will be accessible through every file of your script unless you destroy the session manually or set a time expiration on it..!

Comment: @Sens4 : I did some changes in code..Make sure to use this updated code and take a look at it back again..!